# Create a layout with a titled border in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I want to create a layout with a titled border just like in the Java application screenshot below:

[image: titled border]

Is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Of the top of my head, this seems achievable with a regular layout, a label and a few CSS lines.

Comment: I mean if there is a quick way like in java just setting the titled border name

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be 100% like the image above? If not, you can try the Panel class with default (valo) theme, there's a sample with code at http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/structure/panel

Answer (score 1):

There is no layout which displays the same layout as you shown in image. However vaadin gives flexibility to play around its components look and feel. As #Jorge mentioned, you can have panel and then play around CSS to get the layout like you shown.

There is no ready to use layout like that in vaadin and even don't see the reason to have it one in core vaadin. if someone builds the add-on is different story.